# Loading GameMaker into React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, game-maker

I am working on a more traditional React Native app.  There has been a requirement given to include small mini-games within the app.

I would really like to allow our dev team to utilize a game making tool such as [GameMaker](https://gamemaker.io/).  It allows export of HTML5 assets to run the game as Javascript, so I figured I could load it up in a `WebView` and be done with it.

Apparently it's not that simple :(

I tried the following:

- Export the game and put it's directory into the React Native assets folder (ex. `assets/spackrocks/`).
- Install the `react-native-webview` package.
- Implement the game as such inside of an `Asteroids` page within the RN app:

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

const Asteroids = () => {
    const source = Platform.OS === "ios" ? require("../../assets/asteroid/index.html") : { uri: "file:///android_asset/asteroid/index.html" };

    return (
        <WebView
            styles={style.container}
            source={source}
            allowFileAccess={true}
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            originWhitelist={["*"]}
            onMessage={event => {
                console.log(event.nativeEvent.data);
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default Asteroids;

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
    },
});
```

This loads the `index.html` without issue.  However, the containing `js` file cannot be loaded inside `index.html`.  I get the following output in the console:

```
Error: 'assets/asteroid/html5game/Space%20Rocks.js' cannot be loaded as its extension is not registered in assetExts
```

Appending "js" to `assetsExts` isn't possible from my understanding, as the js file is not a static asset such as an image.

---

I'm unsure how to proceed.  Is there a way to make this happen?  Am I going about it completely wrong?

Thanks for any help :)